# How to generate unique ID field in module in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

Want to generate the unique ID field in the module which will automatically generate the unique IDs. Can anyone help help for this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a function inside of SugarCRM called `create_guid()` which does this exact thing.

Comment: hello , thanks for the answer . i had done this by changing the field in to the auto increment field in the data base.